# Cannot add to another users calendar

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am attempting to allow a user add items to the calendars of other users.
A user logs in and get the token as follows

```
const AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT     = '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const SCOPES             = 'profile openid email User.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared';


$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);
$response = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me")->setReturnType(Model\User::class)->execute();
```

The logged in user can add to their own calendar using

```
$request = $graph->createRequest("post", '/me/events');
$request->attachBody($data);
$response = $request->execute();
```

But, when I try to add to another user with

```
$request = $graph->createRequest("post", '/anotheruser/events');
$request->attachBody($data);
$response = $request->execute();
```

I get the message

```
Resource not found for the segment
```

Have done the admin auth consent, so all should be fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access another user's data you have to use the following url:

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Your request was just in the wrong form and you ended up sending a request to an non existing resource, thus Graph didn't know what to do.
In your case you just need to prepend `/users` (for more information see [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users)).

So your request could look like this:

```
$request = $graph->createRequest("post", '/users/anotheruser/events');
```

Keep in mind that if you are logged in as a user ([token on behalf of a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user)), the calendar you try to access to must have been shared with the logged in user. Otherwise it will fail due to missing privileges as Graph only allows to edit [Calendars](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_get) that are shared with the user. You also need the Permissions `Calendars.Read.Shared` and/or `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` (which you seem to already have aquired).
Calendar sharing is unnecessary if you gain access [without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) as you then automatically have full access to all users.

Currently the Graph API only supports access to shared Calendars but no operations to edit/change the sharing status or see which Calendars are shared with a user. However you can change the sharing status manually over outlook or the powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Url should be something like `Users('anotheruser')/events`. Since you are directly saying `anotheruser/events`. The service is not recognizing another user as a valid segment and throwing the error.